# Invalid URL or resource not found image javafx maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, imageview

[I'm using using the controlfx 11.2.0 library to display notifications when the user logs in, i'm trying to add an image to the notification, but says that the route is invalid or not found.].
link to see an image of my whole code:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/611372/invalid-url-or-resource-not-found-imagen-javafx-maven

i placed the paths similarly to how Scene Builder does it, however using this and others did not work. how should i place them?

edit: My question was answered in the previous link.

```java
public void error(){

    Notifications notifications = Notifications.create();
    notifications.title("Login Error");
    notifications.text("Username or Password incorrect");
    Image image = new Image("@src/main/resources/com/example/pokedb/images/cancelar.png");
    notifications.graphic(new ImageView(new Image(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResourceAsStream("com/example/pokedb/images/cancelar.png")))));
    notifications.hideAfter(Duration.seconds(5));
    notifications.position(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    notifications.show();
}
```

Comment: You mention Scene Builder, which I suppose is why you have a leading `@`. That only has meaning in an FXML file. The `Image(String)` constructor expects either a URL, a file path, or a resource name. For resource names, it would be the same name that you'd pass to `ClassLoader::getResource(String)`. And that means that `src/main/resources` should not be part of the name. See the duplicate for more details.

Comment: As an aside, it does not make sense to load the image twice (you're creating two `Image` objects--attempting to load the same resource--in the code in your question). Just load the image once. And I recommend using the `Class::getResource(String)`, and converting the URL to a string, approach). Additionally, if you're going to open an `InputStream`, then make sure to _close it_ when done with it.